# tricky behaviour in mocking *out*

Tags: clojure, mocking

I have this code:

```
(def x 10)

(def io (java.io.StringWriter.))

(with-redefs [x 11]
  (with-redefs [io (java.io.StringWriter.)]
    (.write io "one"))
  (with-redefs [io (java.io.StringWriter.)]
    (.write io "two")
    (.toString io)))

(with-redefs [x 11]
  (with-redefs [*out* (java.io.StringWriter.)]
    (print "one"))
  (with-redefs [*out* (java.io.StringWriter.)]
    (print "two")
    (.toString *out*)))
```

The first with-redefs block return "two" as expected. The second one returns "onetwo". It is as if it were reutilizing the same mocked **out* for some reason. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: The second block doesn't return "onetwo" - it prints "onetwo" and returns the default Object toString representation of the PrintWriter object.

Comment: Ok, it prints "onetwo". But it also returns "onetwo". See:
    (= "onetwo"
       (with-redefs [x 11]
         (with-redefs [*out* (java.io.StringWriter.)]
           (print "one"))
         (with-redefs [*out* (java.io.StringWriter.)]
           (print "two")
           (.toString *out*))))
returns true

Comment: That might be a difference in our REPL versions, then. That doesn't work in my REPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `*out*` you care about is a thread-local, not the root value. Try:

```
(with-redefs [x 11]
  (binding [*out* (java.io.StringWriter.)]
    (print "one"))
  (binding [*out* (java.io.StringWriter.)]
    (print "two")
  (.toString *out*)))
```

The `with-redefs` macro only alters the root binding; any thread-local bindings are not affected. When code is executed by the REPL server, it is done so in a context that re-binds `*out*` to a client-specific writer, so that output can be captured and sent back to the client for display (otherwise it would go to the *server's* stdout). The original code would probably work if run from the command-line instead of the REPL.

Comment: its worth mentioning with-out-str macro where *out* is bound to a fresh StringWriter http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/with-out-str